# Accessing a type definition in a class/trait vs an object

Tags: scala

In Scala, a type definition inside a class or trait can be accessed via `Class#Type`. A type definition inside an object can be accessed via `Object.Type`.

What are some of the use cases, caveats and gotchas of using one vs the other?

What is a good patten to use for many unrelated classes which, however, have the same type parameter? For example:

```
class ScanUser[T <: User] { ... }
class PrintUser[T <: User] { ... }
```

How can I avoid repeating the type parameter restriction and reuse code?

Comment: Your questions are very broad, and they seem to cover different subjects. Can you say why you have so many classes with this type signature? Why do they need to be generic on `[T <: User]` rather than just taking a `User` object?

Comment: @Tim I think the question is valid... There are incredibly different semantics between `F[T <: User]` and `F[User]`.

Comment: @erip I think the first question is way too broad. The other two questions are a bit more specific, but still very hard to answer without more information about what the OP is trying to achieve. And I still don't see the connection between the first question and the other two.